# How to make function that calculates moving average of a list?

Tags: python, list, function, enumerate

I am trying to calculate a moving average of a list called 'temp_data' in the function below. The moving average data should be stored in a list called 'moving_average'. The code below works in the sense that list 'temp_mov' is printed inside the function (line 12), but not when I call the function later on (in the last line of the code). In that case, I get an empty list. What mistake do I make?

```
   # calculate moving average of a list of weather data

    def make_moving(temps, temp_mov):
            ''' Create moving average from list weather data'''

            cumsum, temp_mov = [0], []
            for i, x in enumerate(temps, 1):
                    cumsum.append(cumsum[i-1] + x)
                    if i>=N:
                          moving_ave = round((cumsum[i] - cumsum[i-N])/N, 1)
                          temp_mov.append(moving_ave)
            print(temp_mov) 
            return temp_mov

  make_moving(temp_data, moving_average)
  print(moving_average)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign a new list to `temp_mov` here:

```
cumsum, temp_mov = [0], []
```

Therefore, `moving_average` is not updated when `temp_mov` changes.

Changing `make_moving(temp_data, moving_average)` to `moving_average = make_moving(temp_data)` and removing the `temp_mov` parameter will solve the problem.